# How to parse arguments into a python list?

Tags: python, argparse

I want to pass any number of strings to a a python program and have them parsed as a list or array:

```
foo.py hello world
foo.py a b e f g ddd qqq vvv
```

etc, up to 200 strings.

I'm using [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) to parse command-line arguments in python. How can I do this? The documentation doesn't give any examples of parsing arbitrary-number of arguments.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`nargs`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#nargs) keyword argument.

```
import argparse

p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('foo', nargs='+')
args = p.parse_args()

print args.foo
```

`nargs='+'` requires one argument.  Usage:

```
$ python test.py a b c
['a', 'b', 'c']

$ python test.py
usage: p.py [-h] foo [foo ...]
p.py: error: too few arguments
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do, e.g:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv[1:])
```

You'll see that `sys.argv` is exactly the list you want (except `sys.argv[0]` is the name of your program, which you probably don't care about -- which is why I'm slicing it out:-).